# GSAP fromTo animation not working properly in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, gsap

When I change something on next js the scroll animation working as expected but If i realod th website then the animation not working as expected. Then animation starting almost ouside of the screen. Here is my next js code,

How can I solve this issue? and how can I optimized this code?

```
'use client'

import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger) 

import Image from "next/image";
import "./process.scss";

import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth';
import StartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Start';
import { useEffect, useRef , useLayoutEffect} from 'react';





export default function ProcessSection() {
  // const  = useRef();
  const root1 = useRef(null);
  const root2 = useRef(null);
  const root3 = useRef(null);

  const processArticleImage1 = useRef(null);
  const processArticleImage2 = useRef(null);
  const processArticleImage3 = useRef(null);

  const processArticleHeading1 = useRef(null);
  const processArticleHeading2 = useRef(null);
  const processArticleHeading3 = useRef(null);

  const process1Desc1 = useRef(null);
  const process1Desc2 = useRef(null);
  const process2Desc1 = useRef(null);
  const process2Desc2 = useRef(null);
  const process3Desc1 = useRef(null);
  const process3Desc2 = useRef(null);

  function animateElement({
    triggerElement,
    start = "top bottom",
    end = "center center",
    scrub = true,
    sx,
    x,
    opacity = 1,
  }) {
    gsap.fromTo(
      triggerElement,
      {
        x: sx,
        opacity: 0,
      },
      {
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: triggerElement,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          scrub: scrub,
        },
        x: x,
        opacity: opacity,
      }
    );
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      // Process image animations
      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleImage1.current,
        sx: -300,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleHeading1.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process1Desc1.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process1Desc2.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });


    }, root1);

    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleImage2.current,
        sx: 300,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleHeading2.current,
        sx: -100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process2Desc1.current,
        sx: -100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process2Desc2.current,
        sx: -100,
        x: 0,
      });
    }, root2);

    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleImage3.current,
        sx: -300,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: processArticleHeading3.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process3Desc1.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });

      animateElement({
        triggerElement: process3Desc2.current,
        sx: 100,
        x: 0,
      });

    }, root3);

    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);
    

  return (
    <section className="processSection" id="ourprocess" >
      <div className="bodyContainer">
        <div className="processSectionWrapper" >
          <div className="processSectionHeading">
            <h1>How We Work!</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="processWrapper container" >
          <div className="process" >
            <article className='singleProcess' ref={root1}>
              <Image className="processArticleImage" ref={processArticleImage1} src="/process/meeting.svg" width={50} height={50} alt="how dsyncro work"/>
              <div className="processContent">
                <div className="contentHeading">
                  <h2 ref={processArticleHeading1}>Project Discovery and Planning</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="contentBody">
                  <p ref={process1Desc1}><span>Embark on a Creative Odyssey:</span> Dive deep into the client&apos;s vision through spirited initial meetings. Uncover the essence of their project goals, painting a vivid picture of the journey ahead.</p>
                  <p ref={process1Desc2}><span>Blueprints to Brilliance:</span>  Bring plans to life! Navigate the digital landscape with meticulous project planning, where wireframes and mockups sculpt the first strokes of your masterpiece..</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div className="process">
            <article ref={root2}>
              <div className="processContent">
                <div className="contentHeading">
                  <h2 ref={processArticleHeading2}>Project Discovery and Planning</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="contentBody">
                  <p ref={process2Desc1}><span>Embark on a Creative Odyssey:</span> Dive deep into the client&apos;s vision through spirited initial meetings. Uncover the essence of their project goals, painting a vivid picture of the journey ahead.</p>
                  <p ref={process2Desc2}><span>Blueprints to Brilliance:</span>  Bring plans to life! Navigate the digital landscape with meticulous project planning, where wireframes and mockups sculpt the first strokes of your masterpiece..</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Image ref={processArticleImage2} src="/process/development.svg" width={50} height={50} alt='How dsyncro development'/>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div className="process">
            <article ref={root3}>
              <Image ref={processArticleImage3} src="/process/meeting.svg" width={50} height={50} alt="how dsyncro work"/>
              <div className="processContent">
                <div className="contentHeading">
                  <h2 ref={processArticleHeading3}>Project Discovery and Planning</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="contentBody">
                  <p ref={process3Desc1}><span>Embark on a Creative Odyssey:</span> Dive deep into the client&apos;s vision through spirited initial meetings. Uncover the essence of their project goals, painting a vivid picture of the journey ahead.</p>
                  <p ref={process3Desc2}><span>Blueprints to Brilliance:</span>  Bring plans to life! Navigate the digital landscape with meticulous project planning, where wireframes and mockups sculpt the first strokes of your masterpiece..</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="processSectoionFooter">
              <span className="CTA-Qoute">
                Get a Qoute
                <StartIcon />
                </span>
              <span className="CTA_Schedule">
                <CalendarMonthIcon />
                Schedule a Call</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I have tryed with strictrules false but it still this problem are happen.